# Add marker over an image that is embedded inside a scrollview in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uiviewrepresentable

Unlike the markers over a map, I was trying to add markers over an image that is embedded in a scroll view ( for zooming and panning ).
I'm using an UIViewRepresentable to achieve the scroll functionality and tap gesture functionality.
Wanted to understand as to how to add a marker.
PFB my code

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct ZoomableView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let uiImage: UIImage
    let viewSize: CGSize
   
    var tappedCallback: ((CGPoint) -> Void)

    private enum Constraint: String {
        case top
        case leading
    }
    
    private var minimumZoomScale: CGFloat {
        let widthScale = viewSize.width / uiImage.size.width
        let heightScale = viewSize.height / uiImage.size.height
        return min(widthScale, heightScale)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = minimumZoomScale * 50
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumZoomScale
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
        
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator,
                                                     action: #selector(Coordinator.tapped))
        
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        
      
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 
        
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let topConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor)
        topConstraint.identifier = Constraint.top.rawValue
        topConstraint.isActive = true
        
        let leadingConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor)
        leadingConstraint.identifier = Constraint.leading.rawValue
        leadingConstraint.isActive = true
        
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        return scrollView
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(tappedCallback:self.tappedCallback)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        guard let imageView = scrollView.subviews.first as? UIImageView else {
            return
        }
        
        
        // Inject dependencies into coordinator
        context.coordinator.zoomableView = imageView
        context.coordinator.imageSize = uiImage.size
        context.coordinator.viewSize = viewSize
        let topConstraint = scrollView.constraints.first { $0.identifier == Constraint.top.rawValue }
        let leadingConstraint = scrollView.constraints.first { $0.identifier == Constraint.leading.rawValue }
        context.coordinator.topConstraint = topConstraint
        context.coordinator.leadingConstraint = leadingConstraint
        // Set initial zoom scale
        scrollView.zoomScale = minimumZoomScale
    }
    
    
}

// MARK: - Coordinator

extension ZoomableView {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var zoomableView: UIView?
        var imageSize: CGSize?
        var viewSize: CGSize?
        var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
        var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            zoomableView
        }
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
            print("zoomScale = \(zoomScale)")
            print("offset =  \(scrollView.contentOffset)")
            print("Content size \(scrollView.contentSize)")
           
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
            print("zoomScale = \(zoomScale)")
            print("offset =  \(scrollView.contentOffset)")
            print("Content size \(scrollView.contentSize)")
            guard
                let topConstraint = topConstraint,
                let leadingConstraint = leadingConstraint,
                let imageSize = imageSize,
                let viewSize = viewSize
            else {
                return
            }
            topConstraint.constant = max((viewSize.height - (imageSize.height * zoomScale)) / 2.0, 0.0)
            leadingConstraint.constant = max((viewSize.width - (imageSize.width * zoomScale)) / 2.0, 0.0)
        }
        
        var tappedCallback: ((CGPoint) -> Void)
               init(tappedCallback: @escaping ((CGPoint) -> Void)) {
                   self.tappedCallback = tappedCallback
               }
               @objc func tapped(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
                   let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
                   self.tappedCallback(point)
               }
    }
}
```

on double tap, I want to put in a marker at that point

Comment: I can help with idea, not very familiar with swiftUI. First decide how you want to show marker - on click or always but controlled. On click is easy, less work, just find where you click and if you need to show it, show a pop-up style marker.  If you wants to show markers always, you need to detect every user interaction with touches and check if there are markers in the visible area. sometimes there will be no marker but sometimes 10 so you will need some functionality to reuse them alongside they must have unique identity.

Comment: once markers are identified, add another layer or view on scrollview (not required to stretched to whole scrollable area) put add your designed marker on it.

Comment: I have got the CGPointValues of where the user taps in on the image view. In the above snippet can you help me in understanding as to how to add another layer on scroll view ?

Comment: I am not very familiar with swiftUI very much but as I can see here it's only zoomable view. Another layer/view will be added over it. Scrollview and layer will have same parent. you can wrap both together in new class later.

Comment: Will try this out, thanks

Comment: I understood the concept, but i'm not able to replicate it into code :(