# Overlay / draw shape over the image view embedded in a scroll view - ios swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have an image view embedded in a scroll view and I understand that, to draw something on the image with scaling functionality, the new view has to be a parent of the scroll view.
I'm not understanding as to how to put it in my code attached below (swiftUI) based.
Have been stuck with this for few days already.

To summarise, the below code adds zoom and pan behaviour to an image and returns coordinates when double tapped using the gesture recogniser

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


struct ZoomableView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let uiImage: UIImage
    let viewSize: CGSize
   
    var tappedCallback: ((CGPoint) -> Void)

    private enum Constraint: String {
        case top
        case leading
    }
    
    private var minimumZoomScale: CGFloat {
        let widthScale = viewSize.width / uiImage.size.width
        let heightScale = viewSize.height / uiImage.size.height
        return min(widthScale, heightScale)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = minimumZoomScale * 50
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumZoomScale
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
        
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator,
                                                     action: #selector(Coordinator.tapped))
        
        gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        
      
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: uiImage)
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
 
        
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let topConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor)
        topConstraint.identifier = Constraint.top.rawValue
        topConstraint.isActive = true
        
        let leadingConstraint = imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor)
        leadingConstraint.identifier = Constraint.leading.rawValue
        leadingConstraint.isActive = true
        
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        return scrollView
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(tappedCallback:self.tappedCallback)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        guard let imageView = scrollView.subviews.first as? UIImageView else {
            return
        }
        
        
        // Inject dependencies into coordinator
        context.coordinator.zoomableView = imageView
        context.coordinator.imageSize = uiImage.size
        context.coordinator.viewSize = viewSize
        let topConstraint = scrollView.constraints.first { $0.identifier == Constraint.top.rawValue }
        let leadingConstraint = scrollView.constraints.first { $0.identifier == Constraint.leading.rawValue }
        context.coordinator.topConstraint = topConstraint
        context.coordinator.leadingConstraint = leadingConstraint
        // Set initial zoom scale
        scrollView.zoomScale = minimumZoomScale
    }
    
    
}

// MARK: - Coordinator

extension ZoomableView {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var zoomableView: UIView?
        var imageSize: CGSize?
        var viewSize: CGSize?
        var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
        var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            zoomableView
        }
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
            print("zoomScale = \(zoomScale)")
            print("offset =  \(scrollView.contentOffset)")
            print("Content size \(scrollView.contentSize)")
           
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let zoomScale = scrollView.zoomScale
            print("zoomScale = \(zoomScale)")
            print("offset =  \(scrollView.contentOffset)")
            print("Content size \(scrollView.contentSize)")
            guard
                let topConstraint = topConstraint,
                let leadingConstraint = leadingConstraint,
                let imageSize = imageSize,
                let viewSize = viewSize
            else {
                return
            }
            topConstraint.constant = max((viewSize.height - (imageSize.height * zoomScale)) / 2.0, 0.0)
            leadingConstraint.constant = max((viewSize.width - (imageSize.width * zoomScale)) / 2.0, 0.0)
        }
        
        var tappedCallback: ((CGPoint) -> Void)
               init(tappedCallback: @escaping ((CGPoint) -> Void)) {
                   self.tappedCallback = tappedCallback
               }
               @objc func tapped(gesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
                   let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
                   self.tappedCallback(point)
               }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add marker over an image that is embedded inside a scrollview in swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71015445/add-marker-over-an-image-that-is-embedded-inside-a-scrollview-in-swiftui)

Comment: nope, I mentioned that I already know that an intermediate view is required but I'm not understanding as to how to put the code in a swiftui way.